# How can I convert a DateTime value to a double?

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I convert a `DateTime` value to a `double`?

Comment: can you be more specific... are you looking for a julian date?

Comment: how exactly do you want to achieve that? you want to convert the time represented in milliseconds to double?

Answer (score 9):

If, by `double` you mean an OLE Automation date, then you can use [`DateTime.ToOADate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx). From the linked MSDN topic:

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose value is the number of days from midnight, 30 December 1899. For example, midnight, 31 December 1899 is represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25; midnight, 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.25.
>
> The base OLE Automation Date is midnight, 30 December 1899. The maximum OLE Automation Date is the same as MaxValue, the last moment of 31 December 9999.

If you're talking about some other date representation that can also be stored in a `double`, please specify...

Comment: *blows smoke off finger tips*

Answer (score 4):

DateTime.ToOADate() converts to a double [OLE Automation Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx) in C#

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OLE Automation date enable `Datetime` to convert to Decimal/double type.  However, the outcome/value to decimal/double is not exact system `Datetime`.

For example,

```
Decimal dateIndDec = Convert.Decimal (Datetim.Today.ToOADate());
```

is not equal to MS SQL

```
 Select Convert (Decimal (10, 9), GetDate())
```

Conclusion: OLE Automation date is not a true system `datetime` info... cannot use it.

I've been searched everywhere about convert `Datetime` value to Decimal value in C# without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate difference between your DateTime and DateTime.MinValue, and then get any `Total*` value.

```
var difference = DateTime.Now - DateTime.MinValue;
Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalMinutes);
Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalMilliseconds);
```