# Convert date time with milliseconds to double or int?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string looking good in the following way:

```
TimeString = "2011.01.02 22:06:52.091"
```

Now I wanna convert it to double, and save it as a double number. I am doing it in c#, how could I do it?

Really can not find answer online.

Edit:

The time is kind of time stamp for financial currency quote:

Time                           bid                   ask

2011.01.02 22:06:52.091     1.5000                1.5001

it is the time stamp of Forex quote time. I prefer in this way: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ooo, the xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is the int part to show how many seconds we have from "2011.01.02 22:06:52" and the .ooo is the milliseconds as "091" how do you think?

Comment: What value to do you expect to get as a result? Ticks, number of milliseconds, etc? Put a different way, how do you plan to use the result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a DateTime value to a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010697/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-value-to-a-double)

Comment: @M.Babcock, actually, it is the time stamp of Forex quote time. I prefer in this way: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ooo, the xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is the int part to show how many seconds we have from "2011.01.02 22:06:52" and the .ooo is the miliseconds as "091" how do  you think?

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE - You may want to add that detail to your question.

Comment: try and put all your info in your question, it tends to be annoying when people drip feed information.

Comment: @M.Babcock, Hallo, I made an edit.

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE - You're still missing some key pieces of information provided by your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var span = DateTime.ParseExact(TimeString,
                            "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) -
        new DateTime(2011, 01, 02, 22, 06, 52, 0);
double d = span.TotalMilliseconds/1000.0;
```

turns it into a double

Comment: @Keith.Nicholas, String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. This is the complaint by running your code.

Comment: sorry, should be HH not hh, changed my code, HH is for 24 hour time.

Comment: actually, changed it to something better :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options, but it's impossible to know what is "best" without knowing the use scenario.

If you can store this as a `long` (Int64), you can use [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx).

The other option is to use [DateTime.ToOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx), which converts the DateTime to an OLE Automation date as a double.

To convert back, you can use the [constructor that takes Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx), or [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String timeString = "2011.01.02 22:06:52.091";

    string format = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.fff";

    double date = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToOADate();

}
```