# Convert Time into Double

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, variables

How may I get the "DateTime" function on a program and convert it into a double variable? My goal is to do some time operations like

(imagine that this variable t1 is a static "time" already written in a label)
(now imagine that t2 is the DateTime from the computer)

```
t1 = 03:40:11
t2 = DateTime

t3 = t2 (that would be DateTime converted) + t1
```

How would I turn this DateTime into double so I can do this operation?

Comment: And why not doing it the other way around??? Parse t1 with `DateTime.Parse` and do all your operations as DateTime, a class that has a lot of specific designed methods for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106415/convert-date-time-with-miliseconds-to-double-or-int

Comment: @Matt that's because you're trying to add two `DateTime` (which makes no sense) however what you really have is a `TimeSpan` (`t1`, you just need to parse it) and a `DateTime` (`t2`) which can be added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert it into a double. You can perform arithmetic directly on the DateTime object:

```
var date = new DateTime(1944, 6, 6, 1, 10, 0);
var time = TimeSpan.Parse("03:40:11");

var newDate = date.Add(time);

Console.WriteLine(newDate); // Prints "06/06/1944 04:50:11"
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple operations are possible on raw TimeSpans. However, you can use it's `TotalSeconds`, `TotalHours` etc. propetries, which are `double`. Later, you can return to the `TimeSpan` world by `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(m1 + m2 * 7.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator for adding two DateTime's. And since a DateTime is an absolute time value it would make much sense to add two absolute time values.

But you can do:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("12:00:00");
DateTime dt1 = dt + ts;             // Adding a TimeSpan to a DateTime
TimeSpan ts1 = DateTime.Now - dt;   // Substracting two DateTimes
```

Comment: I've done like RB and it worked, btw I've found what was missing.
I forgot to call a variable "DateTime" that would be "DateTime.Now" and I finished it doing: var finalTime = dateTime.Add(timeSpan).

Answer (score 0):

I've done like RB and it worked, btw I've found what was missing for my program to do this kind of addition. 
I forgot to call a variable "DateTime" that would be "DateTime.Now" and I finished it doing:

- dateTime = my variable which gets the time from the computer
- timeSpan - my variable which has a static time number

  ```
  var finalTime = dateTime.Add(timeSpan).
  ```

Thank you guys for your help!